# Scala compiler behaviour for Covariance

Tags: scala, types, type-inference, covariance

Following code is running perfectly :

```
abstract class Vehicle{
  val name:String
}
case class Car(name: String) extends Vehicle
case class Bike(name: String) extends Vehicle

case class Parking[T](vehicle: T)

object Covariance extends App {

  def parkMyVehicle(p : Parking[Vehicle]): Unit = println(s"Parking ${p.vehicle.name}")
  parkMyVehicle(Parking(Car("Mercedes")))
  parkMyVehicle(Parking(Bike("HD")))

}
```

This is bit strange, because, `Parking` is not covariant.

However, following line is demanding covariant `Parking`, else not getting compiled (which is expected).

```
parkMyVehicle(Parking[Car](Car("Mercedes")))
```

My question is, why `parkMyVehicle(Parking(Car("Mercedes")))` was not demanding covariant `Parking`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because inference can figure out from the context what type should be. I.e.

```
parkMyVehicle(Parking(Car("Mercedes")))
//            ^ ---------------------^ What's the type of that?
```

since `parkMyVehicle` takes `Parking[Vehicle]`, that what the type *should* be from compiler PoV. So the expression gets typed with an upcast to a superclass:

```
parkMyVehicle(Parking[Vehicle](Car("Mercedes"): Vehicle))
```

This would be different if you extract variable, however:

```scala
val p = Parking(Car("Mercedes")) // Type is first figured out to be Parking[Car]
parkMyVehicle(p) // now the type of p does not match, so it fails to compile
```